# Using asp + ajax + json achieve autocomplete

Tags: ajax, json, asp-classic

My table has six fields, name is:Code,Name,Model,Specif,Brand,Unit.I want at the 'Code' Input tab to enter the first letter, it can ajax request database through JSON returned 10 records,when I select one,Autofill 6 labels.
I have not done before similar projects.I need a complete example, including background processing
sql:

```
set rs =server.createobject("ADODB.RecordSet")
sql="select * from goods where goods_stop=0"
if request("search_code")<>"" then
sql=sql&" and (goods_bar='"&request("search_code")&"' or goods_code like '%"&request("search_code")&"%' or goods_name like '%"&request("search_code")&"%' or goods_letter like '%"&request("search_code")&"%' or goods_short like '%"&request("search_code")&"%')"
end if
```

now I can use lacal json

Comment: If you're not already aware, this style of coding leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Form inside pass a hidden id

Comment: Quite seriously, being a hidden ID will will not make your code safe; it is trivial to alter the values of hidden form values. Use parameterised queries.

Comment: Now this project makes me a headache

Comment: In the submitted query when I pass a hidden form value is a fixed value, the page will give priority in receiving verify this fixed value

Comment: If you have written verification code that stops people searching for `') or 1 = 1; drop table goods; -- `, then it would still have been easier to write this as a parameterised query.

Comment: You are right,Did you have a complete example: using asp and ajax json to complete forms and AutoComplete

Comment: This is the point at which I ask what you've tried already, as StackOverflow is for solving problems not writing all the code.

Comment: Understand, I tried it that I  tryed code

Comment: I want to refresh code under, and then send in another new post on, do you think? Adrian Wragg